# How to block, disable or otherwise prevent the playing of YouTube video ads on MacOS Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, video, big-sur, youtube

On iOS Safari, although not the most convenient, one may refresh the video whenever a video ad comes up at the beginning of the video, and that should pretty much do the job — the video starts immediately thereafter. In fact, one may simply start watching by immediately refreshing once the subaddress of the video starts loading. This bypass may or may not work on iPadOS.

The same, however, does not work on MacOS.

Hence, the question is what add-on, app, terminal code or other solution or work around is available to prevent the ad-disruption of YouTube videos?

Comment: Good luck - this is an arms race and Google is highly motivated to work around most blocks. What works today can break tomorrow. Nothing about that revenue extracting web site or [how they assemble their code targeting macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/440535/5472) specifically is simple.

Comment: Well, even that answer may be a helpful guide post for future wanderers of the Internet to end up and find.

Comment: @bmike I reviewed that question, and although the question is not as specific as this one, the answers generally address the very problem sought an answer for here. In fact, even OP there appears to have actually sought a solution primarily to video ads. Would you be able to close this question, and put a redirect link as answered there? (The question itself is valuable cause someone on search engines may search for it the way I worded it, and could find the answers there.) Thank you!

Comment: Done. The big issue is videos are now chained together and the ads injected in to the cuts so it’s getting harder to process those streams like you would in tivo or if you  removed them with post production tools. Your edit to the other post is superlative work. Great analysis

Comment: @bmike Thank you! Yeah, I know what you mean: "Content creators". You know, that's fine, or I can take that since if you watch those integral ads, you support directly — at times — small businesses, you can apparently also jump over with Vinegar immediately, and not have to worry that it would change the volume as you keep boosting on the right arrow.

Comment: Native video controls are so much more accessible and PIP enablement is 

Comment: Right!? Exactly, this thing is like butter so glad you linked it in the comments, and now I found it.

Comment: I've been using AdGuard for Safari. You see the still from the first ad, but refresh clears it. So long as you then stay in YT & navigate from there, I think that's the end of the ads. If you come in from an external link, you get that first still again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting! I've had AdGuard forever, and it never blocked a single video ad for me. Maybe a detailed answer on how to activate the function would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an app called [Wipr](https://giorgiocalderolla.com/wipr.html) to block ads on YouTube. It works for me both on macOS and on iOS (in Safari). It costs $1.99 as a one-time purchase.

I believe there are free alternatives, but I've had the most luck with Wipr.

Here's a screen recording showing before/after with Wipr: https://gfycat.com/mildanimatedlangur

Comment: My question was clear on its objective, but just to confirm: This is supposed to prevent _video_ ads, correct? (Want to make sure before a potentially disappointing purchase)

Comment: "The app didn't block YouTube video[ ad]s, so I'm giving it one star. I hope there is a way to get a refund, even if it was just $1.99." (Most recent 1-star user review, submitted Sept. 9, 2022, queried Sept. 27, 2022) I guess I'm passing on this one.

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh Yes, it blocks video ads. Don't know what to say, it is a listed feature and it works properly on my computer and on my iPhone - I watch a fair amount of YouTube. Perhaps the user didn't enable the extension properly (there are 4 toggles in the Safari Extensions that are required due to how Safari works)

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh Here's a video showing it blocking regular ads and pre-roll video ads https://imgur.com/a/5hVJLDP

Comment: I tried to view the image, but this is the error message the comes up: "{"data":{"error":"Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."},"success":false,"status":403}" Can you trie and share another screenshot? I'll delete this comment, and will accept the answer if we could confirm this.

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh Sounds like Imgur is having trouble - it's loading for me fine. If you're using a VPN or something perhaps it's blocking the VPN IP address? I can upload it to a different page though, one moment

Comment: @KortellyZamatosh I''ve updated my answer with a Gfycat link

Comment: I watched it, and although I can’t tell if the ad didn’t show in the second video was because YouTube only shows ad videos every now and then or because of the blocker, but I accepted the answer for now. Thanks for the answer!